# Can I use a VB variable inside of an Embedded Javascript section?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<% Dim foo as string = "bar" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var baz = <%=foo %>
</script>
```

Where the `<script>` tag is embedded on my index page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but make sure you put quotes around it and a semicolon:

```
var baz = '<%=foo %>';
```